# End of Buffer and Timeout

Tags: go

I have this method that I want to read the buffer until it reaches the prompt. It works fine when the prompt available in the output but I don't know how can I tell when the end of the buffer is reached.

Also, I want to add a timeout in case the device didn't respond.

```
func (device *Device) readUntil(pattern string) (*string, error) {
stdoutBuf := make([]byte, 65*1024)
output := ""
var validID = regexp.MustCompile(pattern)

for {
    byteCount, err := device.reader.Read(stdoutBuf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Reader read err:%s", err.Error())
        break
    }
    output += string(stdoutBuf[:byteCount])
    //fmt.Println(byteCount, err, io.EOF)

    if validID.MatchString(string(stdoutBuf[:byteCount])) {
        return &output, nil
    }

}

return &output, nil
}
```

Comment: why do you mean by "how can I tell when the end of the buffer is reached" ?

Comment: I mean there is no more data to search for. I am stuck in the loop if the prompt is not found.

Comment: Is the prompt found by using the `validID` regexp?

Comment: Side note: don't use `regexp.MustCompile` like this; use `regexp.Compile` and return the error if not nil. Or, preferably arrange things so that you don't have to re-compile regular expressions (e.g. take a `*regexp.Regexp` which the caller can build once at init time with `regexp.MustCompile` if they're using a hard-coded regular expression).

Comment: Does `device.reader` support `SetReadDeadline` (such as in [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn))?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ticker in a select loop to break from your loop

```
func (device *Device) readUntil(pattern string) (*string, error) {
    stdoutBuf := make([]byte, 65*1024)
    output := ""
    var validID = regexp.MustCompile(pattern)

    timeout := time.After(1 * time.Second)

    for {

        select {

        case <-timeout:
            return nil, errors.New("error timeout")

        default:
            byteCount, err := device.reader.Read(stdoutBuf)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Reader read err:%s", err.Error())
                break
            }
            output += string(stdoutBuf[:byteCount])
            //fmt.Println(byteCount, err, io.EOF)

            if validID.MatchString(string(stdoutBuf[:byteCount])) {
                return &output, nil
            }
        }

    }

    return &output, nil
}
```

Comment: This won't do what you think it does. Your first `select` case creates a new timer channel which will not be readable so the `default` block will get executed.  An `io.Reader` (which is probably what `device.Reader` is) will block until input is available. Even if it didn't, you recreate a new 1 second timer each time through the loop which will never be ready to read.